# Primary key not found when scaffolding controller in MVC core

Tags: c#, asp.net-core-mvc

When trying to scaffold a controller I get the following error:

> "There was an error running the selected code generator: 'The entity
> type 'Company.Models.Office' requires a primary key to be defined at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.CodeGeneration.ActionInvoker.b_6-0()"

I am new to MVC Core but my understanding is that a primary key is defined by default as ID or classnameID.  I have also tried adding the [Key] attribute and renaming the primary key to OfficeID.  I have gone through a similar process with another class and did not run into this problem

```
public class Office
    {
        public int ID;
        public string Name;
        public int SiteID;

    }
```

Answer (score 16, accepted):

I'm not sure if this will resolve your issue, but try the following. The main difference here is using { get; set; } properties.

```
public class Office
{
    [Key]
    public int OfficeID { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public int SiteID { get; set; }
}
```

You should be aware that it doesn't really matter what your primary key is called. However, for easiness and following standards, you should call it either 'ID' or the table/class name plus 'ID'.

Also, try restarting Visual Studio and your PC. Sometimes, I find that this is the only way to resolve some compile time errors.

Comment: Seemed to just require a reset.  Sorry for the bother but thank you for the help!

Comment: Once I added `{ get; set; }` then the scaffolding worked like a charm for me.

Answer (score 7):

I faced a similar issue while scafolding In Asp net core Mvc. Adding this to your 
 Dbcontext file might help!!

```
protected override void OnModelCreating(ModelBuilder modelBuilder)
            {
                base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);
                modelBuilder.Entity<Office>(entity =>
                {
                    entity.HasKey(x=>x.OfficeID);

                });
            }
```

Comment: Ugg, I don't like to hack the context! So this worked for be, because there is no unique key in my view.... and had to change the Get to return more than one item. Thank you much.

Answer (score 3):

Make sure to remove entity.HasNoKey(); from modelBuilder as well.

Answer (score 0):

I found a similar error while scaffolding asp.net core MVC controller method.  The error reported the same error that is in the title of this question.

Here is my POCO for the Model class I entered for Scaffolding an 'MVC Controller with Views, using Entity Framework'

I finally figured out what was missing.  The [Key] attribute was present but the members of the POCO are NOT declared as ***public***.  DON'T FORGET YOUR ***PUBLIC*** KEYWORD!!

```
public class RiskLimit
{
    [Key]
    int Id { get; set; }
    DateTime BeginMappingDateTime { get; set; }
    DateTime? EndMappingDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Once I changed the code to

```
public class RiskLimit
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime BeginMappingDateTime { get; set; }
    public DateTime? EndMappingDateTime { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: He already mentioned that he tried to with the [Key] attribute and obviously he had the public keyword

Comment: This answer make two suggestions on the error, and both are already mentioned in the OP (see comment from @sicKo mentioning this as well), So I do not see, how this makes a good answer.

Answer (score 0):

I just had this issue. I forgot to set a primary key in the SQL table.

I ended up deleting all the model classes, and recreating them using -

`Scaffold-DbContext "Server=.\sqlexpress;Database=YOURDB;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models`

Afterwards, I was able to create the controller.

Answer (score -1):

First, make sure that your table contains primary key, then run following command, in order to create model class using EF Db first approach:

> Scaffold-DbContext
> "Server=DESKTOP-48G00GJ;Database=AXITClassDesignEg;Trusted_Connection=True;"
> Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -f

Note : use `-f` at the end

Then check the DbContext file, that `entity.Haskey` is created.
Go to the controller, right-click add scaffold. Done !!!

Comment: I do not think, that this really answers the question. @coolhand mentions in his question, that he somehow is unable to create a primary key, and in fact, this is what the error message quoted, states as well. In your answer, you just write "make sure a primary key exists", but not giving an answer, how this should be done.