# API Controller with action using Entity Framework value cannot be null

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api, .net-core

I working a project. with **angular 9** and **asp.net core Web api** 
i did the scaffold of the db but when i want to create a controller with API Controller with action using Entity Framework it shows me this error:

[image]

**here my appsettings.json:**
[image]

Startup and the dbcontext:[image]

```
namespace livraison.Models
{

public partial class gestion_livraisonContext : DbContext
{ 

    public gestion_livraisonContext(DbContextOptions<gestion_livraisonContext> options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }

    public virtual DbSet<Agence> Agence { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Client> Client { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ClientPar> ClientPar { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<ClientPro> ClientPro { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Commande> Commande { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Livreur> Livreur { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Responsable> Responsable { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Superadmin> Superadmin { get; set; }
    public virtual DbSet<Ville> Ville { get; set; }


}
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the constructor gestion_livraisonContext class to the following code:

```
public gestion_livraisonContext(DbContextOptions options)
        : base(options)
    {
    }
```

Comment: please see this link : https://stackoverflow.com/a/61533857/5576498

Comment: now i have this erreur : Error while running the selected code generatorthe entity type "Agence" requires primary key to be defined

Comment: @Sohaib El Mediouni you should define primary key for Agence Entity. help link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45470977/5576498